# Calculating the boundary of irregular shape in Cartesian Coordinate 2D

Tags: python, math, algebra, calculus

I'm looking for a solution to calculate the boundary of an irregular shape.

Lats take a look at Square example:
[image: Simple Square]

if i have **Minimum** `x` and `y` and **Maximum** `x` and `y` like:

```
MaxX = 5
MinX = 1
MaxY = 5
MinY = 1
```

in python language:

```
#Python Code
X = {"Min":1, "Max":5} # is Dictionary of x Axis
Y = {"Min":1, "Max":5} # is Dictionary of y Axis
```

I can check if any coordinate is in the square boundary or not, simpley by comparing the axis against min and max of square boundary.

now let's look at these 2 irregular example:
[image]
[image]

Now how can i calculate the boundary and coordinates of the shape? i do have the point coordinate but i don't have the coordinates inside the shape and lines coordinate that connecting every points of the shape.

**Note:** you might suggest for Point-in-Polygon but that's like calculating every time for specific coordinate, and if shape is huge it will take time.

**Note:** even if you heard of a solution in any book, speech, video, website, or even you are guessing, please do let me know in the comment, that could help me out.

Comment: Hace you tried to detect corners? If it si on images, then I suggest you to use dome kind of library specialised on this (like OpenCV). Do it in 2 parts: detect and interpret the scales, then detect the corners in the shape and interpret their points

Comment: What you want to determine is the "concave hull" of the shape...not the convex hull.  Your first figure shows the minimum area bounding rectangle, the second i the convex hull and the final figure is the concave hull (see alpha shapes as well)

Comment: @sop OpenCV, never heard about it, i'll look into it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanPatterson i see... i'm not familiar with those terms, thanks for pointing them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get full list of **integer** coordinates inside the shape, consider using of [floodfill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Comment: How would you know where to start from?

Comment: @sop when i create a shape, each point of it have a number, it's only matter of finding clockwise and counter/Anti clockwise, which is pretty simple, but yes in case if lines are separated like how AutoCAD/Rhino handle the lines then finding the point is another problem.